# how to write pseudocode which returns majority element in array?

Tags: algorithm

Im working on a textbook Algorithms (Dasgupta, C. H. Papadimitriou, and U. V. Vazirani) where Im trying to solve the Textbook problem 2.23. 
However, Im not sure whether my solution is correct. Appreciate any insites!

Given some constraints:

```
n = 2^k,k ∈ N

Runtime = O(n log n)

Use at most O(1) additional memory.
```

I would like to write pseudocode for a function which returns the majority element in a array `B = [b_1,...,b_n]` of `length n with b_i ∈ B`, where only tests for equality and inequality `(b_i = b_j)` can be used.

An element x is called majority element if it occurs more than n/2 times:

```
MajorityElement(A,x) := |{i | i ∈ {1,...,n},b_i = x}| > n/2
```

Given the subarray `B_l,_r = [a_l , . . . , a_r ]` I thought to use a divide-and-conquer algorithm:

```
 function GetMajorityElement(B, l, r, x):
            if x = 1: -- so here I check if array has only one element
                return B[1]
            else l < r: --- here I check if left element < right element 
                midelement<–(l+r-1)/2
                B_lefthalf <– B[ :midelement]
                B_rightthalf <– B[midelement:]
            MEL = GetMajorityElement(B_lefthalf) - recursively repeat
            MER = GetMajorityElement(B_rightthalf)

            if MEL is a majority element of B:
                           return MEL
            if MER is a majority element of B:
                           return MER
            return ‘no majority’
```

I assume the algorithm runs: T (n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n) = O(n log n).

Appreciate any insites/hints and corrections. Thx!

Comment: why oh why would anyone vote to close this?  bizarre

Comment: @fattie: perhaps it has to do with the large number of [potential duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Balgorithm%5D+majority+divide+conquer)? Although I don't have time right now to check which is the best...

Comment: @rici - fair enough.  Someone should find a dupe link.

Answer (score 0):

To find the majority element, we use a basic algorithm called the Moore's voting algorithm.

The algorithm is:

1. Initialize index and count of majority element

   ```
     maj_index = 0, count = 1
   ```
2. Loop for i = 1 to size – 1 ........

   ```
   (a) If a[maj_index] == a[i]
         count++
   (b) Else
       count--;
   (c) If count == 0
         maj_index = i;
         count = 1
   ```
3. return a[maj_index]

Comment: It doesnt run in O(n log n)

Comment: 1,1,2,3,1 how do you know that 1 is majority. Count is only 1.

Comment: @aschoerk: step 3 should read "return a[maj_index] if that element is the majority element; else report there is no majority element." To verify, you need to count occurrences. The point is that the algorithm guarantees to find the majority element *if there is one*.

Comment: No, no change needed. The algorithm finds the majority element if there is one. If you don't know whether there is one, you need to rescan the array, counting occurrences of the candidate. Either it will turn out to be the majority element or there isn't one. (There is no guarantee that it will be the modal element if there is no majority.)

Comment: @rici ok, thank you, but the rescan I would call a change in the algorithm.

Comment: @aschoerk: The OP is not written well enough to know what exactly is needed. If the original question was "write a function which returns the majority element if there is one, with unspecified behaviour if there is no majority element", then the provided algorithm is fine (although the use of `max_index` is a bit unusual). If the original question was "write a function which returns the majority element if there is one and a failure indication otherwise", then the additional verification step is needed and that would be a modification to the algorithm. In no case is sorting useful.

Comment: @rici looking at: 1,1,2,3,1 I think the algorithm could not decide if 1 is majority or not without rescan. I think the result count would be 1 as it would be if the sequence ended already with 3, which definitly is no majority. So the count alone could not be used for the decision except when the sequence was sorted. I see it would be very much effort, much more than the rescan. So, as I can understand until now, the rescan can not be omitted.

Comment: @aschoerk: the final value of `count` is absolutely meaningless. Neither the answer nor my comments imply that it has any meaning. As I said, the rescan can be omitted if you don't care what the function returns when there is no majority element. That may seem strange to you, but it is certainly possible. (For example, you might be lanning to count the number of instances of the element after the function returns, in which case the verification would be a waste of time.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the described algorithm won't work. The decision: "is a majority element of B:" is not clear and might be quite complicated. You will need at least the counts of both majority candidates in both halfs. A minority in the first half can be the majority in both halfs together with the other majority.

Proposed solution:

Divide and conquer can be used for sorting. Later counting and keeping the most frequent element until at least half the sorted set is looked on will allow to find the majority. But you will need O(n) additional space, if you are not allowed to change the order of the elements in the original array.

Additionally you have to be aware that the recursion might cost additional space.

Comment: Obviously, it should read "if MEL is *the* majority element..." (and, indeed, it should contemplate the possibility that MEL is "no majority"). Plus the use of the arguments l, r, x is confusing, to say the least. So I agree that the presented pseudocode has serious problems. But the algorithm itself works fine: divide the array (conceptually) into two equal pieces; recursively find the majority element (if any) in each half; and then check both candidate majority elements by running through the array and counting the frequency (which is O(N)). Sorting is not required.